# Рекурсия в функции draw

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, помогите дописать код, чтобы двоеточие в часах мигало, а время обновлялось без перезагрузки страницы.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id ="ctx"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.onload = init;
        var ctx, canvas;

        function init() {
         canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
         ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            setTimeout(draw,500);
        }

        function draw() {
              // Переменые
                let date = new Date();
                let hours = date.getHours();
                let minutes = date.getMinutes();     
              // Ведущий ноль, проверки и условия

      if (minutes <= 9){

            minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }
      if (hours <= 9 ) {

            hours = "0" + hours;
      }

              // Рисование
             ctx.fillStyle = "Turquoise";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "SteelBlue";
             ctx.strokeRect(10,10,250,150);
            ctx.lineWidth = 25;
            ctx.fillRect(10,10,250,150);

            //  Цифры
            ctx.fillStyle = "white"
            ctx.font = "5em serif ";
            ctx.fillText(hours,25,100);         
            ctx.fillText(":",120,100);    // двоеточие    
            ctx.fillText(minutes,155,100);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ctx, canvas;
var show = true;

...

setInterval(draw, 500);

...

if (show)
  ctx.fillText(":", 120, 100);
show = !show;
```